# How to filter products as per custom attribute value in Magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1, product-attribute, widget

I am trying to sort products as per the custom attribute value "**new_sort_by**" but unfortunately I could not filter.  please check my code

1. Create a product attribute "new_sort_by"
2. add the below code for filter products.

   ```
    $productCollection = $block->getProductCollection();
    $productCollectionnewproducts = $productCollection->addAttributeToSort("new_sort_by","ASC")
                                    ->addAttributeToSort('name', 'ASC');
    echo $productCollectionnewproducts->getSelect()->__toString();
    $itemsnewproducts = $productCollectionnewproducts->getItems();
   ```
3. Used for Sorting in Product Listing = Yes

save the attribute and clear the cache.

also re-index the data.

I am saving products with attribute (new_sort_by) value in number (1,2,3,4,5) and want to sort products with the attribute value in **ASC** order.

Answer (score 0):

check below settings in attribute code

```
Used for Sorting in Product Listing = Yes

save the attribute and clear the cache.

also re-index the data.
```

Comment: I have already these data.

Comment: check if setOrder() method is in your collection.

Comment: I have already checked that but it's not working